# Flutter apply condition on text widget if data isnt available

Tags: flutter, dart

I am showing data in text widget like this

```
                           Text(
                              posts[position]['OrderDetailModifiers'][0]['ModifierName'].toString() ?? 'N/A',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD',
                                  fontSize: 13, color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
```

Issue is some time `posts[position]['OrderDetailModifiers']` is null

right now its look like this

```
     "OrderDetailModifiers": [
        {
          "ModifierName": "Single",
        }
      ]
```

But some time its look like

```
      "OrderDetailModifiers": [
        
      ]
```

Need to know how can I apply condition in my text widget if its null or not available so don't show text widget.

Comment: You need to parse the following if-clause into pieces.                              ` posts[position]['OrderDetailModifiers'][0]['ModifierName'].toString() ?? 'N/A',`

Answer (score 1):

You can make `if` statement in your widget tree.

```dart
if (posts[position]['OrderDetailModifiers'].isNotEmpty)
   Text(
      posts[position]['OrderDetailModifiers'][0]['ModifierName'].toString(),
      ...
   ),
```

Comment: when it's empty it showing an Invalid value: invaid value range is empty : 0

Comment: Might be because OrderDetailModifiers, when empty, is not en empty list value but a `null` value. You might need to change the if condition to `posts[position].containsKey('OrderDetailModifiers') && posts[position]['OrderDetailModifiers'].isNotEmpty`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the length and then show

```
Text(
                              posts[position]['OrderDetailModifiers'].length>0?posts[position]['OrderDetailModifiers'][0]['ModifierName'].toString(): 'N/A',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD',
                                  fontSize: 13, color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using null-aware operators like this:

```dart
void main() {
  printFirstModifierName(data); // Azerty
  printFirstModifierName([]);   // N/A
  printFirstModifierName(null); // N/A
}

void printFirstModifierName(List<Map<String, dynamic>> data) {
  print((data?.firstOrNull ?? const {})['ModifierName']?.toString() ?? 'N/A');
}

extension ListX<T> on List<T> {
  T get firstOrNull => isEmpty ? null : first;
} 

final data = [
  { 'ModifierName': 'Azerty' },
  { 'ModifierName': 'Qwerty' },
  { 'ModifierName': 'Tyuiop' },
];
```

Comment: when it's empty it showing an Invalid value: invaid value range is empty : 0

Comment: Indeed, `first` will throw a `StateError` if the list is empty. Using a `firstOrNull` extension method would work.